# CommandT causing macvim to segv

Tags: macvim

Using ruby 2.0.0. mvim is built with ruby support enabled. Use the .vba approach to install the plugin. Now whenever I launch mvim it SEGVs. If I remove the CommandT plugin all is back to normal.
THe architecture flag is `-arch x86_64` so I didn't override the arch flag to 32 bit when running `make` in the `./ruby/command-t` directory.

Also tried to uninstall and install mvim but no luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

After some more googling found the link: http://arjanvandergaag.nl/blog/compiling-vim-with-ruby-support.html. So yes, vim and CommandT were compiled with different versions of ruby support.

Did the following:

1. `brew edit macvim`
2. Updated --with-ruby-command to point to rvm ruby path which CommandT was using.
3. `brew uninstall macvim`
4. `brew install macvim`

   The original Formula had --with-ruby-command set to ${RUBY_PATH}. So my solution is a little hacky. What's the right way to get brew to follow rvm default ruby path?